# How to connect to a MySQL db via a client on Mac?

Tags: mysql

I'm used to MS SQL and Management Studio on Windows but got MacBook recently, and appereantly, I don't have enough RAM for the tasks I need to do on my Parallels Desktop.
Thus, I installed MySQL on my Mac and been able to create a database via MySQL Workbench.
I can see the database exists when I type in

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

However, whenever I want to connect to the localhost server via a client (Sequel Pro), using the same connection informations as I used to Workbench, I get this error message:

> MySQL said: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be
> loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so,
> 0x0002): tried: '/usr/local/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so' (no
> such file)

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest you to use Docker to run Databases locally instead of installing them.
This gives you lots of advantages (eg: only run it when you need it) and moreover there are plenty of documents around that tells you how to quickly run and connect to it.
For example --> https://dbschema.com/2020/03/31/how-to-run-mysql-in-docker/ (the real first result found *duckduckgoing* it :))

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about using Docker... Love that you duckduck :)